# Any simple tools for re-loading a specified web page periodically (Windows)?

Tags: windows, performance, web

I've got a website that is exhibiting slow performance on the first load and would like to attempt to load it every 5 minutes or so to keep the cache fresh. Are there any simple tools to accomplish this? Scheduled tasks doesn't have quite the time resolution I need. The tricky thing is that this site uses Windows authentication so a wget script won't work. I'm also worried about instantiating a bunch of copies of internet explorer or attempting to kill iexplore.exe tasks blindly.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what webserver you're using. If it's current IIS you could try [Application WarmUp](http://www.iis.net/expand/ApplicationWarmUp). If it's something else, you could look for similar server-side tools.

Answer (score 0):

[WebInject](http://www.webinject.org/) should do the trick - you can run it from a command line script and it should handle the username / password input.

Answer (score 0):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/115

but I don't know what is the windows authentication and if it works with firefox

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using "windows" authentication rather than just standard http basic auth?

you could try

```
 wget http://username:password@domain.com/
```

Comment: Yep I'm sure. Oh well.